# Group rows where str is contained in another row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How could I create 2 columns that flags when the rows in the group are contained in each other? Everything is case-insensitive.

```
   Type        value        
0   Fruit     apple          
1   Fruit      App le 
2   Fruit    Apple yes       
3   Fruit      Apple        
4   Cutlery    Spoon
```

Expected Output

```
dup_index flags, per group, what rows the value is contained within
dup is "yes" if that row is mentioned in dup_index

    type      value        dup         dup_index
0   Fruit     apple        yes         2,3    ("apple" is contained in row 2 and 3)        
1   Fruit      App le 
2   Fruit    Apple yes     yes                ("apple yes" is not contained in another row)  
3   Fruit      Apple       yes         o,2    ("apple" is contained in row 0 and 2 )  
4   Cutlery    Spoon
...
```

I then want the flexibility to drop rows where dup is "yes".

Comment: how many rows do you have? Are your strings only 1/2 words?

Comment: Does the "type" column play any role in the logic of the columns "dup_index" and "dup"?

Comment: Say 10s of thousands rows @mozway. Strings can be a few words but not too long

Comment: Need to groupby type column @ThiagoSC, that's all

Comment: @asd OK, then it will take some time as you have to test all pairs of strings within a group but it should work. The larger the groups, the slower this will be ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and a custom function for [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

```
from itertools import product

def f(g):
    l = g.str.casefold().tolist()
    tmp = pd.Series({(a, b): l[a] in l[b] for a, b in
                     product(range(len(l)), repeat=2) if a!=b},
                   dtype=bool)
    if not tmp.empty:
        return (tmp[tmp].to_frame().reset_index(level=-1)['level_1']
                .groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(g.index)
               )

df['dup_index'] = df.groupby('Type')['value'].transform(f)

df.loc[df.index.isin(df['dup_index'].explode().unique()), 'dup'] = 'yes'
```

*NB. this requires the original index to be unique.*

Output:

```
      Type      value dup_index  dup
0    Fruit      apple    [2, 3]  yes
1    Fruit     App le       NaN  NaN
2    Fruit  Apple yes       NaN  yes
3    Fruit      Apple    [0, 2]  yes
4  Cutlery      Spoon       NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Is there a simpler way to just create ```dup``` without needing to create ```dup_index```?

Comment: @asd well you don't have to assign to dup_index, you can directly go for the last step. Just replace `df['dup_index']` by `df.groupby('Type')['value'].transform(f)`. You can likely optimize it further by avoiding the aggregation+explode but I did design the current code thinking you needed the intermediate ;)